# msg does not send using curl

Tags: php, curl

I am working in php. I want to send sms. Here i have used one api for sending sms. The code is like :

```
$url = "http://link.9starabs.com//httpapi/smsapi?uname=uname&password=password&sender=CARCLK&receiver=9558109779&route=T&msgtype=1&sms=Thanks for inquery ,We will contct you soon.";
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $auth = curl_exec($curl);
```

But I could not receive sms.When I copy this url and paste into browser then it work. So what I have to do resolve this problem?

Comment: For a start you seem to be missing the protocol at the beginning of the URL.

Comment: @JonStirling I have written but its not working

Comment: Then do some debugging. Start with looking at what the exec is returning to you and potentially see if `curl_error()` gives you anything.

Comment: @JonStirling i am new to integrate msg api. So should i have to write anything in **curl_error()** or just i have to print this function?

Comment: Check [the documentation](http://php.net/curl_error).

Comment: @JonStirling i have print **curl_error($curl)** but it prints nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93962/discussion-between-nisarg-and-jon-stirling).

Comment: I have tried this url and it answers a 101 code as response.  I don't have protocol details to know what it means ... bad auth?

Answer (score 0):

It is working from browser means you are missing the `User-Agent` header with your request. You can add the following line with your code to let curl say the request is coming from a browser.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0');
```